# Hp scanner application fails to save a file in Hebrew format

Tags: scanner

I have an HP laserjet M1522NF and i am using the scanner software that comes with the drivers.

what is happening is when i scan a document and try to save the document in Hebrew i get a message:

"Cannot save the file /???.tif" save as with other file formats though i don't think that the file format has anything to do with it.

further more, if i save the file name in English, there is no problem renaming it to 
Hebrew from the file explorer.

Anyone has any idea what can cause this behavior.

Thanks

Comment: it is probably just an issue with the program itself not handling the unicode (or whatever) charachters. You have a workaround, the only thing left to do would be to tell the company/programmer , and ask for a fix.  I think it is useful that someone else can find your question, if they have the same problem with that, or a different language.